# How do I make it say (1) Plane in object and edit mode?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, object-mode

I have a plane in both object and edit mode but near the axes it says 0 plane. Is there any way I can fix this?
(Sorry if my explanation doesn’t make sense)
[image]
[image]

Comment: Press the right arrow on your keyboard. That will change the current frame to the next one that is frame 1. The number indicates current frame.

Comment: Thank you  , sorry for being an idiot‍♀️